# What is the best rational approximation to pi using a 64-bit numerator and denominator?

Tags: c++, c, math, pi

What's the most accurate rational pair for Pi representable with two 64 bit integers? Feel free to include other `int` types if you'd like.

Here's what I came up with, but I'm sure it can get more accurate since the denominator can get substantially bigger - I'm just thinking in base-10. I'm pretty sure the numerator should be something like `uint64` max.

```
// c++
inline constexpr auto pi_num = 3141592653589793238ull;
inline constexpr auto pi_den = 1000000000000000000ull;
// c
const unsigned long long pi_num = 3141592653589793238ull;
const unsigned long long pi_den = 1000000000000000000ull;
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C, C++ or even programming in general.

Comment: @Ayxan Sure it does. I need an accurate `pi` and don't want to use a floating-point number. C++ doesn't allow floating-point numbers as non-type template parameters, so I'm stuck using rational integers.

Comment: This is a math question.

Comment: then update your question to reflect the integer requirement (and why)

Comment: @Ayxan Not really. It's specific to programming, and a situation I'm in with C++. I'm sure it may be useful in the future to other people. This question is rather language-independent, I'll admit - I can remove those tags but I don't know which tags to apply for this.

Comment: @pm100 It feels like unnecessary details. My question is currently clear and concise - I don't want to muck it up.

Comment: @sup it does allow non-type floating point template arguments: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/c5MT9n

Comment: @Ayxan That is C++ 20. No compilers fully support that yet, so it's a moot point.

Comment: @Ayxan If you are going to edit the question, edit it completely and remove the C/C++. Don't just change the tags.

Comment: I removed the language tags. Feel free to roll it back if you think that's not right. I think this is a math question. "I have these numbers to play with, what's the closest pi approximation can I come up with?"

Comment: What you have there is more precise than a `double` (which only has 53 bits of precision). Maybe you can get a bit more precision, but it's probably good enough?

Comment: @ikegami It is more than accurate enough for me but I'm just interested in this in general. It reminded me of the approximation I learned in grade school of `22/7`. I figured it was a neat question.

Comment: Get the most accurate quad-precision representation of PI you can, dump the bytes of the quad, extract the mantissa and exponent, use the mantissa as the numerator and the 2^exponent as the denominator. Chop off bits (and lower the exponent) until the number fits into 64-bits. That'll get you 113 bits of precision (minus those you remove). The point is: You want the denominator to be a power of two so no floating-point loss occurs when you perform the division

Comment: The mathematical part of the question is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations); also the information [here](https://oeis.org/A001203) should be useful.

Comment: Funny thing, even if you get the number stored to that accuracy, you lose a lot of it the second you do any sort of multiplication or division unless you have a result that can handle double the precision size (256 bits here).

Comment: @ikegami That's likely to be good enough, but not likely to be the *best*. 22 and 7 can both be represented in 5 bits, but there's no 5-bit number with a power-of-2 denominator that's a better approximation than 22/7. (25/8 is 3.125, not as good as 22/7=3.142857...).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) to get excellent approximations of an irrational number. If you haven't encountered continued fractions before, it's a way of writing a number as nested series of fractions of the form

[image: a sample continued fraction]

Adding in more and more terms into a continued fraction gives a better and better approximation as a rational number.

The [continued fraction of π](https://oeis.org/A001203) is

```
[3; 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 84, 2, 1, 1, 15, 3, 13, 1, 4, 2, 6, 6, 99, 1, 2, 2, 6, 3, 5, 1, 1, 6, 8, 1, 7, 1, 2, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 16, 1, 161, ...]
```

and so we can write a little Python script to compute approximations based on this continued fraction representation, which is shown here:

```
from fractions import *

digits = [3, 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 84, 2, 1, 1, 15, 3, 13, 1, 4, 2, 6, 6, 99, 1, 2, 2, 6, 3, 5, 1, 1, 6, 8, 1, 7, 1, 2, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 16, 1, 161]

for i in range(len(digits)):
    # Start with the last digit
    f = Fraction(digits[i]);

    # Keep rewriting it as term + 1 / prev
    for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):
        f = digits[j] + 1 / f
    
    # Stop if we overshoot
    if f.numerator >= 2**64 or f.denominator >= 2**64: break
    
    # Print the approximation we found
    print(f)
```

This prints continued fractions with better and better approximations until we overshoot what fits in a 64-bit integer. Here's the output:

```
3
22/7
333/106
355/113
103993/33102
104348/33215
208341/66317
312689/99532
833719/265381
1146408/364913
4272943/1360120
5419351/1725033
80143857/25510582
165707065/52746197
245850922/78256779
411557987/131002976
1068966896/340262731
2549491779/811528438
6167950454/1963319607
14885392687/4738167652
21053343141/6701487259
1783366216531/567663097408
3587785776203/1142027682075
5371151992734/1709690779483
8958937768937/2851718461558
139755218526789/44485467702853
428224593349304/136308121570117
5706674932067741/1816491048114374
6134899525417045/1952799169684491
30246273033735921/9627687726852338
66627445592888887/21208174623389167
430010946591069243/136876735467187340
2646693125139304345/842468587426513207
```

This last approximation is the best approximation of π, I believe, that fits into 64-bit integers. (It's possible that there's a better one that appears between this denominator and the next denominator that you'd get that overflows a 64-bit integer, but this is still pretty close!) Therefore, you'd want

```
const uint64_t pi_num   = 2646693125139304345u;
const uint64_t pi_denom = 842468587426513207u;
```

[This source](http://qin.laya.com/tech_projects_approxpi.html) reports that this approximation is accurate to 37 decimal places (!):

```
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288418 (approximation)
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419 (actual)
```

This should be more than enough for what you're aiming to do. (Unless, of course, you're trying to set a record for finding digits of π or something like that. ^_^)

Comment: Observe that 128 bits are used (two 64-bit integers), and log10(2^128) ≈ 38.5, so 37 decimal places (plus the initial digit) is about what we would expect.

Comment: Very thorough post! Thank you. Would you mind extending it to cover the overflow you mentioned, as if we are hard-coding the numerator to be uintmax?

Comment: @superdeveloper A potential alternative that I have used in some of my code is to represent pi as the *product* of two `double`s: `1.8656436928143307 * 1.6839188885261840 ~= pi`, with an absolute error of 1.6956855320737799e-31. I was provided with this factorization by Tor Myklebust.

Comment: Without explicitly testing all of the remaining numbers in the range with a library that generates high-precision decimal representations, I'm not sure of an easy way to test the rest of the denominators to see if any of them would give a better approximation. Sorry about that!

Comment: I went ahead and tested all the integers - your listed values are the most accurate. Against intuition, `round(max int / pi)` is actually less accurate. The continued fractions actually are the most accurate ratio until the next ratio in the sequence.

Comment: Quite a clever answer! Minor: Recommend `u` suffix. `const uint64_t pi_num   = 2646693125139304345u;` In this case, `2646693125139304345 <= 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. Had it been greater (maybe for the best e or some other math constant) it wold could trigger a warning about an out-of-range constant. Nothing to lose and in general good form to append `u` to unsigned constants.

Comment: Stopping criteria `if f.numerator > 2**63 or f.denominator > 2**63: break` makes sense for _signed_ 64-bit values.  Not certain this is best for 64-bit _unsigned_ division. Note: 2,646,693,125,139,304,345 is 62 bit.  It would be insightful to see the next best fraction and that its numerator > 2^64.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Great suggestions, thanks! Updated.

Comment: As described in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations), the best algorithm is slightly more complex than just truncating the continued fraction.

Comment: @anatolyg: True - one needs to consider the semiconvergents in addition to the convergents. In this particular case, there are six semiconvergents with numerator strictly between `2646693125139304345` and `2^64`; those semiconvergents are best possible _upper_ bounds for π, but not best possible bounds, so `2646693125139304345/842468587426513207` is indeed the best possible approximation to π with both numerator and denominator bounded by `2^64`.

Comment: Johannis Wallis, "De Algebra Tractatus; Historicus et Practicus", Oxford 1685, p. 54, has this data (I annotated with absolute error):  `496638392183958130 / 158084910090576507 (3.75e-35);
 926649338775027373 / 294961645557763847 (1.61e-35);
1356660285366096616 / 431838381024951187 (8.26e-36);
1786671231957165859 / 568715116492138527 (4.19e-36);
2216682178548235102 / 705591851959325867 (1.70e-36);
2646693125139304345 / 842468587426513207 (1.41e-38);
5723397196869677933 / 1821813910320213754 (6.37e-37)`. The last number pair seems to be erroneous.

Comment: Sorry, got the year of publication wrong: Johannis Wallis, "De Algebra Tractatus; Historicus et Practicus", Oxford **1693**. https://books.google.com/books?id=39szm1zaXXAC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=%223618458675%22&source=bl&ots=2lQVTLbBbS&sig=ACfU3U0Xp2F_AdANYRolgLO6Tq3VINcJFw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBipGNudLqAhVPXKwKHVr6AscQ6AEwEnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%222646693125139304345%22&f=false